# Почему выполняется лишний цикл?

Tags: java

Только начал обучение. Java. Задачка из coding games.

https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/power-of-thor-episode-1

На 3 и 4 тесте герой уходит за допустимую границу.

```
while (lightX<initialTX) {System.out.println ("W");
```

Условие `lightX<initialTX` должно перестать выполняться при `lightX=initialTX`. Но почему-то все равно выполняется. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: "Но почему-то все равно выполняется." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Если я правильно понял в примере нет переменных для текущих координат. initialTX не меняется в процессе перемещения персонаже. Это его начальная координата. А вы считаете как будто это его текущие координаты.

Comment: @Igor герой на анимации продолжает движение там, где уже должен был остановиться.

Comment: @coder675 Да, скорее всего Вы правы. Буду переписывать. Спасибо большое!